# Rails7 + Devise のユーザー登録の際にコントローラのエラーが出てしまいました．

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise

私はいま，自作アプリ（もともとRails6）をRails7 に新しく作り直しているところです．
その中でDeviseのエラーに遭遇してしまい，解決方法がわからないので知恵を貸していただきたいです．

##### やったこと1：

少し前にはDeviseでユーザー登録，gmailの送信までは出来ていたのですが，ログアウトが出来なかった（ルーティングまわりのえらーが何故か出た）ので，調べてみてそれらを解消しようとした．

##### やったこと2：

調べてみたら，Rails7とDeviseの記事が出てきたのでそれらを参考にファイルの追加，変更をしてみた（以下の記事を参考にしました．）

- [Rails7+deviseで起こり得るエラーとその対処法](https://qiita.com/MASAHIDE-HIGASHI/items/1f26c04fb5d5c46ab70b)
- [Rails 7.0 + Ruby 3.1でゼロからアプリを作ってみたときにハマったところあれこれ](https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/5c41a7031404c313da1f)
- [RailsでjQueryを読み込まずにmethod: :deleteのリンクを実現する（Routing Error No route matches [GET] ... の対処法）](https://qiita.com/y-temp4/items/2d50feb3ff0d65acdf67)

##### 現状：

`rails db:migrate:reset` もやって，`bin/rails s` をやってみたら，今度は以下の画像のエラーになってユーザー登録もできなくなってしまいました．

必要なことを埋めて，ユーザー登録ボタンを押したら，以下のように表示されました．
本来はホーム画面に遷移して，フラッシュでメールを確認してね，みたいなことが出るはずでした．

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ぱっと見 devise とは関係なく
logger っていう変数がモジュールではなく true って値が入っていて
true.error っていうメソッドを呼び出そうとしてエラーになってるように見えます

なぜそうなってるかはこのコードだけではわかりません
logger モジュールがちゃんと入ってるか
値を上書きしちゃってないか確認してみてはどうでしょうか

Comment: おっしゃる通り、loggerを探してみたらおかしなところがあったのでそこを修正したら直りました！